# how to re-add the double-quotes to make proper JSON string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

The third-party app I use strips out the double-quotes in the JSON string I pass to it.

So when I get it back, it looks like this:

```
'{key:value, key2:value2}'
```

So I am unable to parse to JSON.

How can I re-add the double-quotes so it looks like:

```
'{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}'
```

I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Use a third part app that actually understands JSON :} Anyway, does application treat the input as text (and stupidly strip the quotes) or as JSON and emit a not-JSON value? Also, what would it do for `{"hello:'world,hi'":"bar quux ugh"}` - or what other (very precise) restrictions are in play?

Comment: Are you accessing the JSON in the front end?  You could assign it to a var if accessing in JavaScript, and then replace : and , with ":" and "," if that's a possibility.  Need more detail.  Can you provide literal JSON string you're attempting to access, and literal method of accessing the JSON where you're trying to parse it?  Also, what depth will you be going into your JSON? Because if you're going to put objects within the JSON in the above suggestion may become too simple for your needs.  In that scenario you may need to better solve the issue within the backend.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to name the third party app you're using to output JSON so that we can review any open BZ's, or similar issues that have been experienced in that app.  Some actual code from your project would also be helpful.

Comment: Well, this is invalid JSON then, what if key or value would contain `,`? Like this: `{key:val,ue,key2:value2}` - is first value `val` or `val,ue`, is second key `ue,key2` or `key2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work for you

```
eval '{key:value, key2:value2}'.gsub(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/,'"\1"')
```

at first parse alphanumerics words and adds " arround them, and then it try to evaluate that in order to get a hash, I dont know if that expression will match for all of your data, maybe you have to add spaces or something like that on the regex. But I hope that idea helps to you.

```
2.2.2 :047 > a = eval '{key:value, key2:value2}'.gsub(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/,'"\1"')
 => {:key=>"value", :key2=>"value2"} 
2.2.2 :048 > a.class
 => Hash 
2.2.2 :049 > a
 => {:key=>"value", :key2=>"value2"} 
2.2.2 :050 >
```

without eval

```
2.2.2 :054 > '{key:value, key2:value2}'.gsub(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/,'"\1"')
 => "{\"key\":\"value\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Comment: `a = eval '{key:va,lue, key2:value2}'.gsub(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/,'"\1"')`

Comment: is she has that kind of values?, if she will, will think to improve that regexp

Comment: Why do you ask me?:) I assume you can't predict keys/values and they totally can be with `,` or `:`, so you can't answer without clarification from op, because for now this task is impossible to solve since sample JSON provided is invalid. In fact your solution will fail to eval anything apart from letters and numbers.

Comment: could be, I don't know which kind of values she could have or not, if that values are reduce to a well known values it could work, if not it will be hard to parse.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question.  These will be regular alpha-numeric strings found in a JSON, just the double-quotes get removed.....

Comment: and I have to pass the JSON string not a hash....well, let me check I may already be converting the string to a hash.  the regex helps give me a good start, though.

Answer (score -2):

```
my_string = "hello"
my_string.inspect
```

calling inspect on a string will yield

```
"\"Hello\""
```

You can then call puts

```
puts my_string.inspect
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't really help with the OPs input.

Comment: If you're using a third-party library then you should go with whatever output it provides. However, If you're not using a third-party lib then I think my answer could be utilized in a to_json method which you can customize to fit your specific needed output.